# pull-right bootstrap changing the div order of display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to display divs in which way I have placed, but when I try adding `pull-right`, div orders are getting changed. I need login button to extreme right, but this goes left of the two input boxes. I am trying to get two text boxes left to login button.

I know `pull-right` makes divs float to right, but is there any way I can give preference to the order of placing the divs to its right?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

<div class="row" style="background-color: #332619; color: #fff !important; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">
  <div id="sellerLoginBox" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
    <div class="form-group pull-right">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_Email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group  pull-right">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login_Password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group  pull-right">
      <button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
    <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#" class="forgetPassword">forgot password ?</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle is below

http://jsfiddle.net/mnzp54fm/1/

Comment: Side Note: When using a `code snippet` that has bootstrap, you should include `bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery-version.js`, which I edited and added in for you.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, wrap all the first 3 divs namely: email, password, and login button in another div and pull that div to the right and remove pull right in those 3 divs as shown below

```html
<div class="row" style="background-color: #332619; color: #fff !important; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">
  <div id="sellerLoginBox" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_Email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login_Password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
    <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#" class="forgetPassword">forgot password ?</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your markup a little, like so:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: #332619; color: #fff !important; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px">
    <div id="sellerLoginBox" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6 text-right">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_Email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login_Password" placeholder="Password">
                <button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
        <span class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="forgetPassword">forgot password ?</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**See a running example here**](http://www.bootply.com/3OoyiRX6sx)